# I can’t use tinyMCE in Angular2 Seed application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, package

I’v tried to  use the following https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tinymce tinyMCE package in my app, but i got an error message.

I tried with another editor packages too like CkEditor but the result is same, an error message. (I have the same issue with LocalStorageModule too)

I installed this starter project: https://github.com/matthias-schuetz/angular2-seed/

Has anybody got this or similar issue using Angular2 seed with an external package?

Error Message:(there is no syntax error i checked the js file)

```
    system.conf.js:25 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:8080/src/app.module.js:24:26)
        at eval (http://localhost:8080/src/app.module.js:57:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:8080/src/app.module.js:58:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:8080/angular2-tinymce
    Evaluating http://localhost:8080/src/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:8080/src/bootstrap.js
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/src/bootstrap.js
(anonymous) @   system.conf.js:25
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:232
Zone.run    @   zone.js:114
(anonymous) @   zone.js:502
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:265
Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:154
drainMicroTaskQueue @   zone.js:401
ZoneTask.invoke @   zone.js:339
```

app.module.ts

```
.
.
.
import { LocalStorageModule } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { PostProjectService } from './components/postproject/+service/postproject.service';
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';
import { TinymceModule } from 'angular2-tinymce';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TinymceModule.withConfig({}),
        HttpModule,
        PostprojectModule,
        BrowserModule,
        SharedModule,
        RegistrationModule,
        DashboardModule,
        ErrorModule,
        HomeModule,
        LoginModule,
        routing,
        // LocalStorageModule.withConfig({
        //     prefix: 'app',
        //     storageType: 'localStorage'
        // })
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AUTH_PROVIDERS
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: `system.conf.js:25 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` <= usually indicates that you are trying to load an HTML resource which could be an error message from the server where a javascript resource is expected. Look at the browser's network calls and find the exact complete path that is being retrieved, most likely there is an error in the path itself OR its a permissions issue.

Comment: I'v got this error in that case when this  TinymceModule.withConfig({}), module is used in app.modeul.ts => imports[] section. Over the  network tab each request has 200 status code. (I added 777 permission to whole project's directory)